# Drop Down Menu in Blackberry 10 Cascade

Tags: qt, drop-down-menu, blackberry-10

I new to Blackberry and qt. I want to make a drop down menu like android drop down menu. I had search and found nothing. I only found about drop down list not drop down menu. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu choices for a Cascades application:

1. Action menu (shown on the bottom action bar if you app has one configured as well has swiping from the right)
2. Context menu (press and hold an item to display a partial view, hold/drag out to reveal complete menu)
3. Application menu (up to five menu items at the top of your app)
4. Custom menu (whatever you can think up by accessing the bb::system::MenuManager)

You can read more about all the menus [HERE](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/ui/navigation/menus.html)

If you want something that is specifically like android's drop down menu you can always explore option #4 and make a custom one.

Comment: can i make the action menu become a header?

Comment: @FaisalSilitonga No I do not believe you can. You can use the application menu but it requires the user to swipe down from the top bezel, or you could create your own custom menu that was displayed always at the top using option #4. Although BlackBerry recommends you utilize one the predefined types (options #1, #2, #3) as much as possible.

Comment: I want to tried using context menu because it the only one which related to my problem(from my point of view). Thank you

Comment: Are you know an example using option #4?